# How to find the integral for $\int^1_{\frac{1}{1+e^\sigma}}(\frac{y}{1-y})^{1/r}\frac{1}{y-1} dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I find the solution for following integral.

$$\int^1_{\frac{1}{1+e^\sigma}}(\frac{y}{1-y})^{1/r}\frac{1}{y-1} dy$$

where $r,\sigma$ are positive constants.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $\frac{y}{1-y}=t^r$?

Comment: Don't be so worried use this link,
https://www.integral-calculator.com/
If it fails I am sorry!!! But most probably it will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int^1_{y_0}(\frac{y}{1-y})^{1/r}\frac{1}{y-1} dy, y_0=\frac{1}{1+e^\sigma}<1$$
$$-I=\int_{0}^{1} y^{1/r}(1-y)^{-1/r-1} dy-\int_{0}^{y_0} y^{1/r}(1-y)^{-1/r-1} dy $$
$$-I=B(1+1/r,-1/r)-B(y_0, 1+1/r,-1/r)= \frac{\Gamma(1+1/r) \Gamma(-1/r)}{\Gamma(1)}-B(y_0,1+1/r,-1/r)$$
$$\implies -I=\frac{1}{r}\Gamma(1/r)\Gamma(-1/r)-B(y_0,1+1/r,-1/r) $$$$\implies I=\pi \csc(\pi/r)+B(y_0,1+1/r,-1/r).$$
$B(a,b)$ is Beta function and $B(x,a,b), 0<x<1$; is incomplete Beta function.

See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 0):

To make the story short since @Z Ahmed already adressed the problem in terms of the beta function, you could write
$$\int_a^1  y^{\frac{1}{r}}\,(1-y)^{1-\frac{1}{r}}\,dy=\frac{\pi  (r-1) }{2
   r^2}\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{r}\right)-B_a\left(1+\frac{1}{r},2-\frac{1}{r}\right)$$ Now, if $a$ is small, you could use
$$B_a\left(1+\frac{1}{r},2-\frac{1}{r}\right)=a^{\frac{1}{r}}\left(\frac{ r}{r+1}a+\frac{ (1-r)}{2 r+1}a^2+\frac{ (1-r)}{2r(3 r+1)}a^3+O\left(a^4\right)\right) $$

Using $\sigma=\pi$ and $r=e$, the "exact" value should be
$$I=0.38992993433\cdots$$while the above truncated expansion gives
$0.38992993411$